# PNG image not showing on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, png

I have an issue making a mobile version of a website. **PNG** images are not showing up on iPhone while the website runs fine on Android phones.

The page just contains some div, a background and a transparent PNG behind text.

This PNG's weight is ~180kb and it is already transparent but I am modifying it's opacity again with CSS.

I've tried many ways but none seem to work.

[Here](http://pianissimo-reze.fr/v2/mobile) is the mobile website URL.
And [here](http://pianissimo-reze.fr/v2/mobile/handm.png) is the PNG Image's URL.

---

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```
<div id=photofond><img alt="" src="handm.png" /></div>

#photofond {
opacity: 0.5;
position: absolute;
top: 23%;
z-index: -1;
}

#photofond img {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit a question and add "Edit" or "Solved". If one of the answers gave you the solution, mark it as accepted. If you found the answer yourself, you can consider adding it as such and then mark it as "the" answer.

Answer (score 0):

With an image positioned in that way you should probably use the CSS `background-image` instead of the HTML `<img>` tag. Take a look at http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/.

It's (very) basic usage is but I'd advise you take a look at the link:

```
#element {
    background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Forgot to say that you are probably best using an photo editing software to reduce the opacity of the image for the best cross-browser support.

Comment: Yeah I did made it this way at first but changed it thinking that it might have caused the problem.
Anyway I found the solution, a simple problem with the z-index, the img did appeared, but underneath the background... strange that it wasn't the same on android.
Thank you for your response and your advice about the opacity !